# How to make an NSWindow only resizable vertically?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos, interface-builder, nswindow

I have a Window in my NIB which is resizable, but would like to enforce it to only be resizable vertically. How can I go about doing this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In IB's size section, for both minimum and maximum width give the same value then you will not be able to re size horizontally.

[image: Refer the following screenshot]

Comment: But how to let the mouse not show as resizable cursor?